# Iterate through each Model record to look through it relational model collection

Tags: laravel-5.5

**I have contract Model like below**

```
class ContractModel extends Model
{
    public $table = 'tblcontracts';
    public $primaryKey = 'Contract_ID';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Payments() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\PaymentModel", "Payment_ID", "Payment_ID");
    }
}
```

I have to get the Latest Payment Date from the list of relational records from Payment method above for each Contract Model.

I was searching it on google and found **[Accessors Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)**

**Update - 1**

I created a method like below in Model class above.

```
public function getPaymentsNameAttribute($value)
{
    dd($value);
}
```

I was assuming that when this code executes `ContractModel::all();`, the control goes to its model class for each record one by one and thus I would be able to make changes in each instance of ContractModel record, But seems like this is not working.

AM I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `latestPayment` relation in `ContractModel` model like this:

```
public function latestPayment() 
{
    return $this->hasOne("App\Models\PaymentModel", "Payment_ID", 
           "Payment_ID")->orderBy('payment_date ', 'desc');
}
```

Now when you build the query `$contractModels = ContractModel::with('latestPayment')->get();` you will get `PaymentModel` with latest payment date for each `ContractModel`. After that you can loop through collection. 
**For example:**

```
foreach($contractModels as $contractModel)
{
   if(!is_null($contractModel->latestPayment))
     {
         dump($contractModel->latestPayment->payment_date);
     }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution inside a model class only. so, when I write let, I was say `ContractModel::all();`, the control should go to the model for each record automatically. and there in the model, I should be able to change the each record. I remember, I was able to do it. But, unfortunately, I forgot it completely.

Comment: @Pankaj It's difficult to understand what you really want to do. Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: Please check update 1 in the  question. I rewrote it.

Comment: @Pankaj Accessor like this `getPaymentsNameAttribute` can help you modify `payments_name` property in `ContractModel` model only. If you want **to get the Latest Payment Date from the list of relational records ** you need to do like in my answer.